# How to fix problem with recorder in G1ANT

Tags: recorder, g1ant

I'm trying to use recorder to record action in google chrome. Actually I see an error message. How to fix it?

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

The addon you are using is experimental and has not been finished. We are currently working on a new recorder which will be superior to that one. We will publish it in a near future. Moreover we don't recommend using application recorder for web automation. You should use selenium addon instead.